# Caching issue with domain access and media image

Tags: caching, media, domain-access

If I clear the cache and access the node with media image from a user with no domain access to image, am I going to get empty field from the cache if I access it from super admin?

I am currently using memcached.

Comment: It depends. If you configured your cache system properly, you will get proper results. There many caching systems and myriad ways to configure them.

Comment: I see, I just want to confirm since there are times where the cache give us information of media image and sometimes it does not. upon checking the sql queries, domain access filter from the first load will sometimes return image if it is from the super admin. But if the first load (after clearing cache) is from user on the other domain with no rights to image, the cache stored is empty.

Comment: Caching after permission check is never good idea. You should either make an exception and not cache these images at all, or key their cache to user. Or, if you don't mind that everyone may load them from cache, if allowed person was first to open them, forget setting permission on them altogether.